# Faraday Law: Exercise

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Exercise:
Two circular figures $R_1$ and $R_2$ are represented in the image, respectively with radius $r_1 = 21,2cm$ and $r_2 = 32,2cm$. In $R_1$ there is a uniform magnetic field $B_1 = 48mT$ in the perpendicular direction coming in the sheet, and a uniform magnetic field $B_2 = 77.2mT$ in perpendicular direction leaving the sheet (all effects on the edge are neglected). Both fields decrease by $8.5mT / s$. Calculate $\int \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}$ for each of the three paths shown in the figure.
[image]

How can i approach this problem? I don't understand what kind of reasoning i have to do about the decreasing of the magnetic field.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first circle, using Faraday's law, you get
$$\int \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}=-\frac{d\Phi}{dt}=-A\frac{dB}{dt}$$
$$=-\pi(0.212)^2(8.5 \times 10^{-3} T/s)$$

Comment: The fact that the initial magnetic field is $48mT$ does not affect the calculations in any case? I do not understand why it is revealed then

Comment: Nope, it makes no difference.  The change is all that matters.  Physics problems often contain unneccesary information.

Comment: ok thanks, to find C instead i must consider the union of the two magnetic fields? or is there any other things to do?

Comment: C will be the sum of A and B.